# How to load files dynamically in an AIR app? Do I have to use the File class?

Tags: file-io, air

I have an XML file that specifies the image files that I need to load. The XML file and the  image files live in a subfolder relative to where the AIR app lives.

I need to load the XML file and also the images (load them and add them as children to a movieclip)

In my AIR app, when I tried to load it via the URLRequest, it didn't work.

```
myLoader = new URLLoader();
myLoader.load(new URLRequest(xmlFilename));
myLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);
```

(I know this works from a .swf b/c I've tested it)

I've found some sample which uses the File class and here's my code and this does work:

```
var aFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( xmlFilename );
var aStream:FileStream = new FileStream();
aStream.open( aFile, FileMode.READ );
configXML = new XML( aStream.readUTFBytes( aStream.bytesAvailable ) );          
aStream.close();            
processXML();
```

...

I'm now trying to load the images specified in the XML file and I'm finding that I have to use the File class to reference the image in the file system.

```
var engImageFile:File = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath( "./english/"+ engFilename ); 

ldr = new Loader();
var urlReq:URLRequest = new URLRequest( engImageFile.url );
ldr.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener( Event.COMPLETE, engImgLoaded );
ldr.load(urlReq);
```

Is this the way that AIR accesses files (using the File class) when it wants to read/load/etc. them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the [documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/filesystem/File.html#applicationDirectory) it states that if you use the File class to access files then this is safe across all platforms. Also the .url property of the File object will use the appropriate URL scheme...

- "app:" - relative to the application directory
- "app-storage:" - relative to the special application storage directory
- "file:" - all else...I think if you specify an absolute path

Answer (score 0):

if I understand your question correctly, I belive you just need to load it as a data source/array, which you can then bind to a component of your choosing.